# Database Structure without Delimited Values

Tags: database, database-design, android-sqlite

I'm creating an application to manage recipes and want to store my data in a database. The main problem is creating an appropriate database structure.

The structure of my objects in the program are:

```
 ________________________________
|Recipe                          |
|--------------------------------|
|-String recipeName;             |
|-List<Ingredient> ingredients;  |
|-List<String> methodSteps;      |
|________________________________|
 ___________________________
|Ingredient                 |
|---------------------------|
|-String ingredientName;    |
|-Float ingredientAmount;   |
|-String ingredientUnit;    |
|___________________________|
```

The program stores a List. Each Recipe can have as many ingredients and methodSteps as the user wishes and both must be greater than 0 and contain valid data.

I couldn't figure out how to create a valid database which adhered to 1st Normal Form as I don't want to hold comma separated values inside the database. There is plenty information saying not to use CSV inside a record which I agree with, just don't have the know-how to implement what I want (or don't know the key search terms to find the information I need).

How can this be translated to a database structure? (Some key values may be added to properly implement the database.

Ultimately this will be run as an Android application so will be using SQLite to manage this inside the Java code.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Points for not putting comma-separated values in a db table.

It's really quite simply: When there are multiple X's that go with a given Y, you create two tables, one for X and one for Y. Then each X must have a reference that ties it to Y.

In this case, you should start by thinking of 3 tables:

```
Recipe
  recipe_id (probably an auto-assigned sequential number)
  name

Ingredient
  ingredient_id
  recipe_id
  name
  amount
  unit

MethodStep
  methodstep_id
  recipe_id
  sequence
  text
```

Note that Ingredient and MethodStep both contain a recipe_id, so you can tie each back to the recipe that they belong with. You'd get all the ingredients for a given recipe with a query like

```
select name, amount, unit from ingredient where recipe_id=?
```

Where "?" is replaced with the appropriate recipe number.

I put a "sequence" on MethodStep because I presume the steps must be done in the right order. then

```
select sequence, text from methodstep where recipe_id=? order by sequence
```

I'd go one more step and create a separate table for units of measure. Like

```
Unit
  unit_id
  name
```

Then instead of putting the name of the unit in each ingredient record, you would put the unit_id. The advantage of this is, (a) It gives you a standardized spelling for all unit names, and (b) You can now add additional information about the unit to the unit table without having to repeat that information in every ingredient record. Like you could give metric equivalents. Or record the relationship to other units, like how many teaspoons in a tablespoon. Then if you want to change quantities, you could have the program automatically multiply and adjust the units, like instead of saying "30 teaspoons" say "10 tablespoons" or however many cups that is or whatever.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! Looks like a very sound structure with a great explanation. With the structure you proposed I'm sure I'll be able to save and load my objects from code to and from this database! Will feedback hopefully when it's all implemented.